# Can a FireMonkey app be launched from a push notification?

Tags: android, ios, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I have an app that I'd like to send push notifications to. But I understand that if I've shut down the application (especially on iOS at least until iOS 7) that push notifications won't launch it (either in the background or the foreground).

I understand the PushKit framework has been added to iOS 8+, and that one of the things it can do is cause an application to launch in the background (and I presume handle my push notification).

Is there a way to trigger this functionality in FireMonkey? Does the same sort of functionality exist for Android as well?